# Multiple action for a single button swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to place multiple actions for one button so that I can move freely with a press of a button.

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation {
       viewModel.sendCode()
    }
```

I want to create another action to go to `WelcomeView` (like action :`goWelcome()`) but it is not working together.

```
}, label: {
    Text("Send Phone Number")
        .font(.headline)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60)
        .background(Color("Primary"))
        .cornerRadius(6)
        .shadow(color: Color("Primary").opacity(0.8), radius: 6, x: 1, y: 1)         
})
```

```
func goWelcome() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: WelcomeView())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do multiple things on one press, simply add more things in the action's `{}`:

```swift
Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.sendCode()
            }

            goWelcome()          
        }, label: {
            Text("Send Phone Number")
})
```

If you want to have multiple gestures at once, use `.simultaneousGesture()`. e.g. if you want to have an extra action after holding the button for certain time:

```swift
Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.sendCode()
            }       
        }, label: {
            Text("Send Phone Number")
}).simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2).onEnded { _ in
    goWelcome()
})
```

`minimumDuration:` is the time in seconds after which an action happens